# Как вывести звезда?

Tags: javascript

У меня имеется такой блок `<span rating></span>`
Сейчас у нас просто серая звезда, но если добавить к ней класс check, то будет жёлтая. Так вот, у меня есть js const, в ней я указал просто 4 и как мне вывести теперь 4 жёлтых звезды и одна серая? Как мне так рассчитать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const count = 4;
document.body.innerHTML = '<span class="rating check"></span>'.repeat(count) + '<span class="rating"></span>';
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}

.rating {
  background: grey
}

.rating.check {
  background: yellow;
}
```

---

> когда напишу const 1, то будет 1 жёлтая и 1 серая, а нужно 1 желтая и 4 серых. Всего же 5 звезд –

```js
const allStarsCount = 5;
const yellowStarsCount = 4;
const greyStarsCount = allStarsCount - yellowStarsCount;
document.body.innerHTML = '<span class="rating check"></span>'.repeat(yellowStarsCount) + '<span class="rating"></span>'.repeat(greyStarsCount);
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}

.rating {
  background: grey
}

.rating.check {
  background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Удивляюсь вашей способностью - понять такие вопросы и дать ответ.

Comment: @eccs0103 на самом деле я написал хоть что-то. Что конкретно у автора имеется и какая конкретно реализация интересует - не имею понятия))

Comment: спасибо большое))))

Comment: @jsususi если ответ правильный, отметьте его галочкой. А за хороший ответ можете и "голос за" давать.

Comment: Хотя "голос за" с рейтингом 1 недоступна. Но галочку можно.

Comment: Кст не правильно, я когда напишу const 1, то будет 1 жёлтая и 1 серая, а нужно 1 желтая и 4 серых. Всего же 5 звезд

Comment: @jsususi надо **корректно** описывать исходные данные. В текущем варианте ответ полностью отвечает на описанные в вопросе условия, а какие у вас дополнительные всякие условия никто читать мысли не умеет

Comment: @jsususi добавил второй вариант, динамический. В след. раз надо подробнее и правильнее описывать исходные данные. В этот раз - галочку слева тык

Comment: спасибо большое)